# Xbee S2 modules firmware is not updating as coordinator

Tags: xbee, zigbee

I am using two Zigbee s2 module(XB24-ZB, ver- 22A7), one as coordinator and other as router. I am trying to communicate  between these two but firmware is getting updated only for Zigbee router AT and it is failing to update as Zigbee coordinator AT.
I am using X-CTU configuring tool sparkfun breakout board.

Comment: Recovery procedure--> http://www.digi.com/support/kbase/kbaseresultdetl?id=3402#XBee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had quite the same issue, only I wanted to update to API mode:

coordinator -> XB24-ZB/ZigBee Coordinator API/21A7

router-> XB24-ZB/ZigBee Router API/23A7

First I tried to update them via my Arduino (plus a Xbee Adapter Kit), but it didn't work.

I found [this site](http://www.digi.com/support/forum/4912/xbee-firmware-10cd-cant-overwrite-other-firmware-version) and following steps worked for the coordinator:

- upgrade to XB24-ZB/ZigBee Coordinator API/21A0 (one version erlier to the newest one)
- afterwards I could update to 21A7...

During the updates a prompt shows up, which says you have to reset your module.

To do so I just had to disconnect the Xbee and reconnect it.

But as mentioned, this only worked for the coordinator.

I tried similar tricks for the second Xbee, without success.

So I took my [FTDI Serial USB Cable](http://www.adafruit.com/products/70) and tried it again.

This did it, I didn't even had to reconnect the Xbee via the update process.

Though I could see all information of my Xbees and also could send data between them, when connected to the PC via my arduinos, I could not update to another firmware without any problems.

My advice: use the FTDI Serial USB Cable - makes it a lot easier...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same update related problem but in my case I needed to upgrade from End-Device-AT 28A7 (XB24-ZB) to Router AT. I failed many times with no valid bootloader error. Then I tried Guti_Haz solution -> updated first to Coordinator API 21A0 (upgrading to the highest version wasn't possible)-> Then moved to Router AT 22A7.

I failed twice in the latest update but it failed during the writing phase so I just tried more times.

Best